# Querying Piwik in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, analytics, matomo

I'm using Piwik to track analytics on my Drupal 7 site. The Piwik module is installed and tracking perfectly. The problem I'm having is with reporting using the PHP method. When I use the sample code from the Piwik docs, it causes an error that causes the entire page to show as plain text HTML/source, instead of the rendered website. However, using the code on a basic PHP file outside of Drupal works fine.

This is the code from Piwik docs (which I modified with to include my auth token):

```
<?php
use Piwik\API\Request;
use Piwik\FrontController;

define('PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH', realpath('../..'));
define('PIWIK_USER_PATH', realpath('../..'));
define('PIWIK_ENABLE_DISPATCH', false);
define('PIWIK_ENABLE_ERROR_HANDLER', false);
define('PIWIK_ENABLE_SESSION_START', false);

// if you prefer not to include 'index.php', you must also define here PIWIK_DOCUMENT_ROOT
// and include "libs/upgradephp/upgrade.php" and "core/Loader.php"
require_once PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH . "/index.php";
require_once PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH . "/core/API/Request.php";

FrontController::getInstance()->init();

// This inits the API Request with the specified parameters
$request = new Request('
            module=API
            &method=UserSettings.getResolution
            &idSite=7
            &date=yesterday
            &period=week
            &format=XML
            &filter_limit=3
            &token_auth=anonymous
');
// Calls the API and fetch XML data back
$result = $request->process();
echo $result;
```

If I change the defined constants to true, it then shows a page that has the error:

session has already been started by session.auto-start or session_start()

Drupal's .htaccess already has the auto.start turned off, and I also tried change Piwik to store session data in the DB instead of files, but neither worked.

Just FYI, the code was placed into a node template (node--183.tpl.php) in order to override the output of a single page.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `This is the code from Piwik docs` => do you have a link to that documentation? I don't understand why there is `FrontController::getInstance()->init();`

Comment: Nevermind I found it: http://developer.piwik.org/guides/querying-the-reporting-api#call-the-piwik-api-in-php It's actually the code you can use if you are inside the Piwik application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are using works if you are within the Piwik project.

If you want to call Piwik from your Drupal application, you can [use the **HTTP API**](http://developer.piwik.org/guides/querying-the-reporting-api#call-the-piwik-api-using-the-http-api). Here is the code example from the docs:

```
<?php

// this token is used to authenticate your API request.
// You can get the token on the API page inside your Piwik interface
$token_auth = 'anonymous';

// we call the REST API and request the 100 first keywords for the last month for the idsite=7
$url = "http://demo.piwik.org/";
$url .= "?module=API&method=Referrers.getKeywords";
$url .= "&idSite=7&period=month&date=yesterday";
$url .= "&format=PHP&filter_limit=20";
$url .= "&token_auth=$token_auth";

$fetched = file_get_contents($url);
$content = unserialize($fetched);

// case error
if (!$content) {
    print("Error, content fetched = " . $fetched);
}

print("<h1>Keywords for the last month</h1>");
foreach ($content as $row) {
    $keyword = htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode(urldecode($row['label']), ENT_QUOTES), ENT_QUOTES);
    $hits = $row['nb_visits'];

    print("<b>$keyword</b> ($hits hits)<br>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the HTTP API currently, but it's a little slower so I was just curious if there was a way to use the PHP method from within Drupal. But, it appears that is not possible. Thanks for checking.